# Не работает скрипт анимации nextjs 14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nextjs

Разбираюсь с nextjs 14(Пользовался react года 3 назад)
Пытаюсь адаптировать https://codepen.io/bradtraversy/pen/dJzzdB Split Landing Page для next 14
Js скрипт для анимации не работает

```js
const left = document.querySelector(".left");
const right = document.querySelector(".right");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

left.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  container.classList.add("hover-left");
});

left.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  container.classList.remove("hover-left");
});

right.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
  container.classList.add("hover-right");
});

right.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  container.classList.remove("hover-right");
});
```

```css
:root {
    --container-bg-color: #333;
    --left-bg-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    --left-button-hover-color: rgba(161, 11, 11, 0.3);
    --right-bg-color: rgba(7, 5, 5, 0.8);
    --right-button-hover-color: rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.3);
    --hover-width: 75%;
    --other-width: 25%;
    --speed: 1000ms;
  }
  
  html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 20%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  
  .button {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    height: 2.5rem;
    padding-top: 1.3rem;
    width: 15rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border: #fff solid 0.2rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  
  .split.left .button:hover {
    background-color: var(--left-button-hover-color);
    border-color: var(--left-button-hover-color);
  }
  
  .split.right .button:hover {
    background-color: var(--right-button-hover-color);
    border-color: var(--right-button-hover-color);
  }
  
  .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--container-bg-color);
  }
  
  .split {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .split.left {
    left:0;
    background: url('./../public/kupan.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  .split.left:before {
    position:absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--left-bg-color);
  }
  
  .split.right {
    right:0;
    background: url('./../public/podgoroy.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  
  .split.right:before {
    position:absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--right-bg-color);
  }
  
  .split.left, .split.right, .split.right:before, .split.left:before {
    transition: var(--speed) all ease-in-out;
  }
  
  .hover-left .left {
    width: var(--hover-width);
  }
  
  .hover-left .right {
    width: var(--other-width);
  }
  
  .hover-left .right:before {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  
  .hover-right .right {
    width: var(--hover-width);
  }
  
  .hover-right .left {
    width: var(--other-width);
  }
  
  .hover-right .left:before {
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  @media(max-width: 800px) {
    h1 {
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
  
    .button {
      width: 12rem;
    }
  }
  
  @media(max-height: 700px) {
    .button {
      top: 70%;
    }
  }
```

```html
import splitcss from '../../../styles/split.module.css'
import '../../../styles/global.css'
import Script from 'next/script'

export default function split() {
    return (
        <body>
            <div className='container'>
                <div className="split left">
                    <h1 className={splitcss.h1}>Купанское</h1>
                    <a href="#" className="button">Read More</a>
                </div>
                <div className="split right">
                <h1 className={splitcss.h1}>Подгорная</h1>
                    <a href="#" className="button">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Script src="splt.js" />
        </body>
    )
}
```

В консоли иногда(Вообще не понимаю как это работает) проскакивает  ✓ Compiled /not-found in 223ms (586 modules)

Пробовал и script, и Script
Вот структура
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Прочитайте про хук `useState()` и посмотрите на вот этот пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65010686/adding-and-removing-a-classlist-in-react-js